# How to unify results of multiple NEO4J queries

Tags: neo4j

I am a newbie in `Neo4J`. I have a question about combining results of several simple queries in `neo4j`. For example:

```
MATCH (p:people)-[:live_in]->(c:countries)
         RETURN p.name AS name, c.name AS countries
```

and

```
MATCH (p:people)-[:has_friend]->(n:people)
     RETURN p.name AS name, n.name AS friends
```

and      etc.

I expect a result in a table as follows:

```
|name|countries|friends|
```

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: If one people (or person) has no country but has friends, should we return this person on the query? OR if this person has no friend but lives in a country, should we also display this person on the result?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query to get the name, countries and friends in one query. Please remove OPTIONAL in countries or friend if a country or friend is required.

```
MATCH (p:people)
WITH p
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:live_in]->(c:countries)  
WITH p, c.name AS countries
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:has_friend]->(n:people) 
RETURN p.name AS name, countries, n.name AS friends
```

Comment: Unfortunately that creates a cross product between countries and friends. That's probably not what is desired, at least if a person can have more than one :live_in relationship to a country. If that restriction holds, however, then this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The output format you probably want here is one row per person, with a list of their countries, and a list of their friends.

This is easiest to do with pattern comprehensions to capture the results of a pattern expansion into a list. This has the advantage of coping with cases where the pattern doesn't exist, as you get an empty list without wiping out the row.

Also it makes more sense to use singular tense for node labels. `:Person` instead of `:people`, since a result from a MATCH pattern will be a person, not a group of persons.

Using singular tense, capital case for labels, and all caps for relationship types:

```
MATCH (p:PERSON)
WITH p, [(p)-[:LIVES_IN]->(c:Country) | c.name] as countries,
 [(p)-[:HAS_FRIEND]->(f:Person) | f.name] as friends
RETURN p.name AS name, countries, friends
```